# Objects in JSON file is not populating the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

***function***

Populate the objects in the dropdown into the dropdown menu. The Json file is stored in the root/ajax/*.json while the working file is stored in root/*.html.

***Issue:***

None of the objects in the JSOn file is populating the dropdown menu. I have tried to console.log(data)  but it is not returning anything. I have got no idea what has failed in calling up the JSON file to populate the dropdown menu.

I have tried 2 methods in calling for the JSON file:

```css
#dropDownShops_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 330px;
  height: 59px;
  z-index: 90;
  top: 340px;
  left: 350px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#dropDownShops_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 330px;
  height: 59px;
  z-index: 90;
  top: 535px;
  left: 350px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
}
select {
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: transparent;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("../lib/image/Dropdown_arrow.png") 100% / 100% no-repeat #eee;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <!-- DropDown Menu to choose Participating Outlet -->
  <select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>


  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

***JSON FILE:***

There are 400 items, but for simplicity i have downsized to just 3 items:

```
{
"Shops": [
{
    "ShopName": "7-ven",
    "ShopID": "7-ven123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-31"
}, {
    "ShopName": "8Tarstries",
    "ShopID": "8Tarstries123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-K4"
}, {
    "ShopName": "A|hange",
    "ShopID": "A|hange123",
    "Shoplocation": "#01-202"
}]   
}
```

***METHOD 1:***

I have tried to use this method but nothing was shown in the dropdown menu and nothing is shown in the console.log

```js
//get a reference to the select element
var $select = $("#dropDownShops_1, #dropDownShops_2");

/*******************************************************
 *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
 *******************************************************/
$(function() {
  //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
  $.getJSON('ajax/shops.json', function(data) {

    $select.html('');

    $.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {

      console.log("value:" + value);
      //iterate over the data and append a select option
      $select.append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
    });
  });

});
```

***METHOD 2:***

I have tried to use this method but it is displaying "none available" as it will directly call the error:function():

```
//get a reference to the select element
    var $select = $("#dropDownShops_1, #dropDownShops_2");
/*******************************************************
        *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
        *******************************************************/
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/shops.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                $select.html('');
                $.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {

                    console.log("value:" + value);
                   //iterate over the data and append a select option
                   $select.append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error:function(){
                //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you using jquery inside [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @bansi i dont think it matters though

Comment: When the `error` callback is called what is the actual error?

Comment: @nnnnnn when the error callback, it is shows "none available" in the dropdown menu, instead of "Please Select Shops ..."

Comment: Yes, because that's what your error "handling" code does. But what is the actual error? jQuery passes details of the error to your function, but you haven't done anything with that information. Any errors in your browser's dev tools Network tab?

Comment: @Luke  Have you got data properly from ajax function

Comment: try the full prototype of `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` and see what is available in `textStatus` and `errorThrown`. btw `error` is depreciated.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I have tried a console.log and have got this in return in my error function: readyState:4, responseText: the objects from JSONfile , status:200, statusText: OK

Comment: @Pravin what do you mean?

Comment: @bansi, thanks, I found the issue. resolved.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks. I found the issue. resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data={
"Shops": [
{
    "ShopName": "7-ven",
    "ShopID": "7-ven123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-31"
}, {
    "ShopName": "8Tarstries",
    "ShopID": "8Tarstries123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-K4"
}, {
    "ShopName": "A|hange",
    "ShopID": "A|hange123",
    "Shoplocation": "#01-202"
}]   
}
 
$.each( data.Shops, function( key, value ) {
var $select = $("#dropDownShops_1, #dropDownShops_2");
 $select.append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>


  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: check attached http://plnkr.co/ which I get data from external file  check if your missing something